# Text to BufferedImage without involving Font

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I'd like to create some images. With Graphics2D it works fine. But when trying to `drawString` I get an exception because the system I have to make it run on doesn't have fonts.

There must be some minimal "text to image" library that doesn't rely on system fonts, right?

Comment: How would you expect the library to draw the text without font that describes the graphical representation of each character?

Comment: I expected it to have something like that but maybe hardcoded and not relying on system files.